# Azure Function 3.1 throws Base-64 string exception on VS2019

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I have created Azure Function with netcoreapp3.1 (LTS). Function interacts with Data Lake so these dependencies are added:
[image: Packages]

This is how my code looks like:

```
    [FunctionName("FixJson")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        await FixJson(log);

        return new OkObjectResult("Json Processed");
    }
```

As soon as I start the solution in Debug mode and sends an [HTTP](http://localhost:7071/api/FixJson) request I get this error:
[image: Exception]

I also tried Publishing the Function on azure but that also throws same exception.

Comment: Are you getting the error from the `FixJson` method ? What happens when you comment out `await FixJson(log);` line ?

Comment: So the problem was in FixJson method. I was trying to access data lake files and credentials were not in correct format. The error didn't make sense hence I kept looking at Azure function level.